# video responsive de manera local

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive, html-video

Buenas tengo un problema con un video para que sea resposive de manera local sin iframe

este es el codigo en html

```
      <!--Video-->
      <div id="trailer" class="section d-flex justify-content-center embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9" >
        <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls autoplay loop muted>
              <source src="/img/COMBI CAFE ACONCAGUA.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Este navegador no acepta este formato.
        </video>
      </div>
```

el cual se ve asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de que manera se puede solucionar?

Comment: Como se supone que quieres que se vea ???

Comment: Debes especificar, recuerda que cada video es una resolución y no todos serán iguales

Comment: Si esos bordes negro y resposive para celular

Comment: a perfecto lo voy a probar